# Showing confirm message only sometimes in window.onbeforeload event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When there are unsaved changes in my app I want to make sure the user does not close the window/tab without seeing a confirmation dialog.

I wrote this:

```
var _beforeWindowUnload = function(event) {
    if (documentHasUnsavedChanges()) {
        // document is dirty
        var message = "Unsaved changes will be lost";
        event.returnValue = message;
        return message;
    } else {
        // document is clean
        event.returnValue = null;
        return null;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', _beforeWindowUnload, false);
```

The problem is when the document is clean I still see the dialog with "null" message. I have tried with `true` and `false` too but no luck.
I also tried not returning anything when document is clean but then when it is dirty it won't show a message. This is odd!

How can I optionally avoid the confirmation dialog while still having the event listener?

---

Note 1: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) says the following but apparently is not true?:

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog.

Note 2: This should work on relatively new browsers.

Comment: Try removing the else completely! null is obviously not void

Comment: *I also tried not returning anything when document is clean but then when it is dirty it won't show a message.* Please show that attempt.

Comment: I think I was doing it wrong. This worked! `var _beforeWindowUnload = function(event) {
    if (documentHasUnsavedChanges()) {
        var message = "Unsaved changes will be lost";
        event.returnValue = message;
        return message;
    }
};`